# How to import a custom exception from ejb project to ejbclient project??

Tags: java, ejb

I have this scenario:

EJB PROJECT

```
public BussinessException extends Exception {}
public MyInterfaceImplementation implements MyInterface {}
```

===

EJB PROJECT CLIENT

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void foo() throws BussinessException;    
}
```

but BussinessException is not in EJB PROJECT CLIENT classpath..
how to resolv this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to go around this is creating a client jar where you package everything that your clients might need to consume your EJBs, included interfaces, data objects and exceptions, then that jar can be imported in both your clients and your EJB project. In the long run, when you want to extend your client jar you should be careful not to break backward compatibility so that your old clients can still consume your EJB project.

EJB PROJECT

```
-MyInterfaceImplementation
-.../lib/client.jar
```

CLIENT JAR (client.jar)

```
-BusinessException
-MyInterface
```

EJB PROJECT CLIENT

```
-..../lib/client.jar
```

this way, both `EJB PROJECT` and `EJB PROJECT CLIENT` have access to `BusinessException` and `MyInterface`.